# Google Maps shows constantly rotating direction despite other compass apps working correctly

Tags: google-maps, sensors, nexus-5x, compass

Google Maps reports rotating direction (0.5 rotations / minute) with stationary phone. The compass is calibrated and works correctly in compass-specific apps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6uOI5g8xbc

**Steps to replicate:**

After booting into Safe Mode and calibrating the compass via rapid figure-8's (or slow, or rotations on table), the direction in Google Maps slowly rotates.

EDIT: I did a factory reset and, before logging in, Google Maps still has this error. I think it may be a hardware bug at this point.

**Apps affected:**

- Google Maps (Safe Mode and normal mode)
- GPS Status (only available in normal mode)

**Apps not affected:**

- "Compass" (orange circle logo)
- Sensors Multitool (shows correct magnetometer readings for X, Y, and Z. Confirms correct calibration)
  https://goo.gl/photos/SavNsaY2PyNPa17G8

**Troubleshooting steps I've tried:**

- Calibrating compass

  - Rebooting in Safe Mode
  - Disabling/re-enabling Google Maps (includes data/cache deletion)

**Specs:**

- Nexus 5X
- Android 6.0.1
- Google Maps 9.34.1

Comment: Confirmed on S4, i9505, with cyanogenmod 13, Google maps 9.40.02

Comment: worth noting, for anybody that doesn't know, i think that blue arrow, when the compass is calibrated, is just meant to point to the top of the phone.. (so not that useful imo, unless a map rotates so that the top of the map is where you are going).It's be good if google maps had an actual compass particularly for when the map is stationary.I use a proper compass with my phone with google maps, that works nicely! then i get a compass 'displayed'(to my eyes), as well as no issues with 'calibration' of it! +often when walking I don't hit start.. unless i want to see an update for Metres/time left

Answer (score -1):

Same issue here on my Galaxy S-6 Edge Plus.  The blue dot/shadow spins rapidly.  Master reset did not fix.  Verizon actually replaced the phone and the new phone acts up as well. I went to Best Buy Samsung help desk and they mentioned an issue that is going to be corrected (soon) as an update to Google Maps. I hope this rapid spinning doesn't mess up any of the sensors on the new phone...

Comment: So you got the phone replaced because of a google maps issue and you are surprised that the new phone acts up? it's a google maps issue

Comment: You wrote "I hope this rapid spinning doesn't mess up any of the sensors on the new phone..." <-- What are you saying here. How is google maps going to be messing up sensors on a phone. Sensors are hardware. Google maps is just an app that reads from sensors, and google maps has whatever bugs it has.  It's like saying you hope stackoverflow doesn't make your hard drive go up in smoke.